# Rails 4 - Precompiling assets failed - unable to precompile assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I am having a rough time in Rails 4.

I had someone on upwork try to help me integrate a wrap bootstrap theme into my Rails 4 app.

Part of that upwork solution was to rename one of my `app/assets/stylesheets` files to `profiles.scss.erb` (it was previously just `profiles.scss`). In my `application.scss`, I then import `@import "<%= asset_path("profiles.scss") %>";`
 (as opposed to all of my other imports which just name the file rather than a path in ruby tags).

That all works fine in development mode.

When I try to push however, I get an error that says:

```
Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
```

The first line identified as a problem says:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: /assets/profiles.scss.
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? Know how to help to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to sass rails assets helper, `asset-path("rails.png") returns "/assets/rails.png"`, therefore in your case `@import "<%= asset_path("profiles.scss") %>"`, it will look for the file in `assets/profiles.scss` and that is not the correct path of `profiles.scss.erb`.

To import `scss.erb` files, you can do the same as other `scss` files, by using `@import "profiles"` and it will return `assets/stylesheets/profiles.scss.erb`